# Interactive stacked area chart in plotly?

Tags: plotly

I can create a stacked area chart with plotly, such as the *Stacked Area Chart with Original Values* in [this tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/)

But, I would like to update the chart when a trace is deselected. That is, if my plot was the example above, I would like the *trace2* to be re-plotted when *trace1* is deselected.

Is such functionality built into plotly somewhere?

Comment: I am using plotly in Python, but a general plotly answer would be helpful as well.

Comment: What do you want to obtain? If you want to have trace 0 and trace 1 to fill till 100% I think you should use [dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) with a dropdown menu. It's possible (but can be tricky to code) to obtain similar results on a static html file playing with `visible` check [this](https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/) at section **Update Dropdown**